# Running gitlab pipeline with jdk17, gradle and docker, docker command not found on test stage

Tags: docker, image, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I made simple Dockerfile :

```
FROM docker:latest AS docker

FROM gradle:7.4-jdk17 AS gradle

FROM docker AS final-docker
FROM gradle AS final-gradle
```

I am using image made from it in my gitlab pipeline. My goal is to use a docker command to run another image inside one of stages (gradle and jdk is needed in all stages). This stage looks like this :

```
unit_test_job:
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux  
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  stage: unit_test
  script: 
    - docker run --detach --name mycontainer -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --rm apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
    - gradle unitTest
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
```

jdk and gradle commands are working correct but docker commands are not recognized:

```
$ docker run --detach --name mycontainer -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --rm apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
/usr/bin/bash: line 141: docker: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I did a lot of research trying to find what can be wrong but cannot find anything. Please help me to resolve the case, explain why it doesn't work and correct these lines to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The image you're using does not have `docker` installed. You need to either install docker as part of your image or specify an `image:` that already has docker installed, e.g.:

```
unit_test_job:
  image: docker
```

The problem is that your Dockerfile you used for building your image probably doesn't work how you expect.

The final image built from the Dockerfile you shared would be the same as if you simply a dockerfile like so:

```
FROM gradle
```

Multi-stage docker builds do not combine the images, as you seem to be expecting. Only the last `FROM` statement constitutes the final built image. All the other `FROM` statements in your Dockerfile effectively do nothing as-written.

If you want docker *and* gradle in the same image, you might do something like this:

```
FROM gradle
RUN apt update && apt install -y docker.io
```

Comment: I did in start of pipeline, as i said this image is added and start of pipeline, but i only showed here stage, if i paste here image it will replace whole image, i dont want to lose gradle and jdk17 in this stage

Comment: @lotto2552 Thanks for the clarification. I missed/misunderstood your meaning in the question. I've edited my answer accordingly.